# How to use partition for the following scenario

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to solve this problem with a window function but I am still struggling. I have 4 columns tbl1 (date, id1, id2, metric). My table looks like the following.

Input

Date     | id1 | id2 | metric.

1/1/2019 |  1  | 123 | 1

1/2/2019 |  1  | 123 | 1

1/3/2019 |  1  | 999 | 1

1/4/2019 |  1  | 999 | 1

1/5/2019 |  1  | 123 | 1

1/6/2019 |  1  | 123 | 1

I tried the following Code.

```sql
select date, id1, id2, rank() over(partition by id1, id2 order by date)
from tbl1
group by 1,2,3
```

This code is returning 2 rows. However, I want to see my output in 3 rows shown below.

Required OutPut

Min Date | Max Date | id1 | id2 |

1/1/2019 | 1/2/2019 |  1  | 123 |

1/3/2019 | 1/4/2019 |  1  | 999 |

1/5/2019 | 1/6/2019 |  1  | 123 |

Comment: What is your question?  You have not described the logic you want to implement.

Comment: seems like islands and gaps question.

Comment: My apologies, I want the output as mentioned above. Currently, I am only getting 2 rows in my output but I want 3 as shown above.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: When I use the window function rank () over (partiton by id1, id2 order by date) the result is 2 rows and that makes sense. However, I want to partition my data to get the output shown above. Let me know if I am missing anything. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  If you would edit your question to add some detail about the logic you are trying to perform that would help others to be able to solve your question and it will provide help for others searching on similar questions/answers later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have a gaps-and-islands problem (you might also be looking for adjacent pairs of similar values, for instance).

If so, you can subtract a sequence from the date to get the groupings and then aggregate:

```
select min(date), max(date), id1, id2 
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id1, id2 order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id1, id2, (date - seqnum * interval '1 day');
```

Comment: Thank you so much!